# How to pass the username and password for accessing a webservice from an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

How to pass the username and password for accessing a webservice from an iPhone application?

Comment: 1) Why is this CW? 2) Please be more specific. Are you accessing a REST web service? Are you using some generic login system or OAuth or whatever? etc etc

Answer (score 0):

New member, probabily made a mistake.
One way to do it is shown here: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mtgr8-zenfolio/